# GWT 2.6 - RequestFactory Locator Could not find domain method similar to

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I am new to GWT and using the version 2.6 with RequestFactory but I am running into GWT validation problems. Somehow GWT cannot find the method on the domain side once I started using Locator and LocatorService (before this, everything worked just find for me).

Below is my implementation:

My request factory looks like this:

```
public interface MyRequestFactory extends RequestFactory {
    MyRequest createRequest();

    @Service(value = MyModel.class, locator = MyModelServiceLocator.class)
    public interface MyRequest extends RequestContext {
        Request<MyModelProxy> find(String id);
    }
}
```

My service locator looks like this:

```
public class MyServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {
    private static MyService serviceInstance;

    private static MyService getServiceInstance() {
        if (serviceInstance == null) {
            serviceInstance = new MyService();
        }
        return serviceInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getInstance(Class<?> klass) {
        return MyServiceLocator.getServiceInstance();
    }
}
```

My service looks like:

```
public class MyService {
    public MyModel find(String id) {
        // implementations
    }
}
```

But GWT validation complains about not being able to find 'MyModel find(String)' on the domain side. But once I put this method into `MyModel` class (which I don't really want to), it works just fine.

I tried to google around and found couple of related posts but none of those problems actually applied to me. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the methods in `MyRequest` have their domain counterparts in `MyService`, then `@Service` should point to `MyService.class`, not `MyModel.class`.

The fact that you use a `ServiceLocator` tells RequestFactory that it should look for instance methods rather than static methods, and will use the `ServiceLocator` to get an instance of the service pointed to by `@Service`. In the case you had had a matching `find` method in `MyModel` (i.e. compile-time validation would have passed), then you'd have encountered an error at runtime because the `MyService` instance returned by your `ServiceLocator` cannot be cast to the `MyModel` that you refer to in your `@Service` annotation.